# error while mapping json string to model class object

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

Below is the json which i want to read and map to the class model object.

```
{
    "models": [
        {
            "model": {
                "code": "YY77A",
                "type": "AUTO",
                "source": "IN",
                "name": "Sams",
                "feature_types": [
                    {
                        "feature_type": {
                            "code": "8H",
                            "desc": "All Models"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "feature_type": {
                            "code": "my20",
                            "desc": "MY20"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "feature_type": {
                            "code": "my21",
                            "desc": "MY21"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "model": {
                "code": "PPuY",
                "type": "HOM",
                "source": "IN",
                "name": null,
                "feature_types": [
                    {
                        "feature_type": {
                            "code": "8H",
                            "desc": "All Models"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "feature_type": {
                            "code": "MY21",
                            "desc": "MY21"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Model class:**

```
class FeatureType2{
    public String code;
    public String desc;
}

class FeatureType{
    public FeatureType feature_type;
}

class Model2{
    public String code;
    public String type;
    public String source;
    public String name;
    public List<FeatureType> feature_types;
}

class Model{
    public Model model;
}

public class Root{
    public List<Model> models;
}
```

Below is the code used to map the json to model (Root.java)

```
// import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper; // version 2.11.1
// import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty; // version 2.11.1
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
Root root = om.readValue(myJsonString), Root.class);
```

Below is the exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "code" (
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "code" (class com.samp.qc.Model), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "model"])
at [Source: java.io.StringReader@15f53014; line: 1, column: 30] (through reference chain: com.samp.qc.Root["models"]->
com.samp.qc.Model["model"]->com.samp.qc.Model["code"])
```

When mapping the json string to the model object it is showing the above exception. what would be the better way to map json String to Model class object.

Answer (score 1):

You have made small error in your Model & FeatureType class. I correct as below and it worked for me.

```
    public class FeatureType2{
        public String code;
        public String desc;
    }

    public class FeatureType{
        public FeatureType2 feature_type;
    }

    public class Model2{
        public String code;
        public String type;
        public String source;
        public String name;
        public List<FeatureType> feature_types;
    }

    public class Model{
        public Model2 model;
    }

    public class Root{
        public List<Model> models;
    }
```

Let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: Root class has List<Model> models.

Comment: So you just fixed two typos: 1) in `FeatureType` to refer `FeatureType2 feature_type`, 2) in `Model` refer `Model2 model`.

Comment: @AlexRudenko yes

Comment: @Digsb Pls see the model class in the post above, can i have only class Root as public and all other classes without access modifiers and i noticed you made all the class as static, is it required to make static?

Comment: @user222, No static is not required, that I added for my code to work. As far as Access modifiers are concerned, classes need to be accessible to ObjectMapper. You can have them an Inner classes, but they should be accessible.